# python pandas: how to group by and count with a condition for every value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have table like this:

```
d  group
1   a
2   b
3   a
4   c
5   f
```

and I like to iterate over values of d and count number of rows that have group=a .

Here is what I am doing now, but It does not work:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for x in (1,5):
        if row['d'] > x:
            row['tp'] = df.groupby('group').agg(lambda x:x.manual_type=='a')
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Sorry what's wrong with `df['group'].value_counts()['a']` or `len(df[df['group']=='a'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df['group'].value_counts()['a']
```

in general, you should NEVER use for loops in pandas.  it's inefficient and usually recreating some existing functionality in the package.