# How to groupby and count on different conditions?

Tags: pandas

```
is_correct, question_id
t           1
t           1
f           1
f           1
t           2
t           2
```

Desired results:

```
correct_count, incorrect_count, question_id
2              2                1
2              0                2
```

This is what I have, but I can only get a correct count

```
df[df["is_correct"]].groupby("question_id")["question_id"].count()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas: how to group by and count with a condition for every value in a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458703/python-pandas-how-to-group-by-and-count-with-a-condition-for-every-value-in-a-c)

Comment: It is a duplicate. Although the solution by MaxU for this question has a better and more interesting answer than the other one

Comment: Then kindly mark the other question as a duplicate of this, so that all are led to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pivot_table function for that:

```
In [28]: data = """\
   ....: is_correct  question_id
   ....: t           1
   ....: t           1
   ....: f           1
   ....: f           1
   ....: t           2
   ....: t           2
   ....: """

In [29]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

In [30]: df['count'] = 0

In [31]:

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
  is_correct  question_id  count
0          t            1      0
1          t            1      0
2          f            1      0
3          f            1      0
4          t            2      0
5          t            2      0

In [32]:

In [32]: df.pivot_table(index='question_id', columns='is_correct',
   ....:                values='count', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)\
   ....:   .reset_index()
Out[32]:
is_correct  question_id  f  t
0                     1  2  2
1                     2  0  2
```

Comment: @samol, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a groupby after creating another column that you will use for counting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'is_correct':['t','t','f','f','t','t'],'question_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2]})
df['to_sum_up']=1

is_correct question_id   to_sum_up
t           1            1
t           1            1
f           1            1
f           1            1
t           2            1
t           2            1

df2 = df.groupby(['question_id','is_correct'],as_index = False).sum()
```

Once you've made your groupby, you just have to rearrange your data so that it fits the columns you want:

```
df2['correct_count'] = df2.ix[df2['is_correct']=='t','N']
df2['incorrect_count'] = df2.ix[df2['is_correct']=='f','N']
```

Then in order to have a nice dataframe as output:

```
df2.ix[df2['correct_count'].isnull(),'correct_count'] = 0
df2.ix[df2['incorrect_count'].isnull(),'incorrect_count'] = 0
df2 = df2.groupby('question_id',as_index = False).max()
df2 = df2.drop(['N','is_correct'],1)

      question_id   correct_count   incorrect_count
0     1             2               2
1     2             2               0
```